# NESTJS: ResolveProperty get Args

Tags: nestjs

I want to get the args of the request in the resolveProperty method to allow nested filtering. 
But the arg is always undefined.

Here is my code:

```
@ResolveProperty('user')
async getUser(
  @Parent() subtest,
  @Args('filter') filter: UserFilter,
): Promise<User> {
  const { userId } = subtest;
  return await this.userService.findOneById(userId);
}
```

Is it possible to get the args in the ResolveProperty method and if so how?

**Solution**

You need to add an argument to the attribute in your graphql file.

Example:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String  
  friends(where: FriendsFilter): [Friends!]
}
```

Comment: What does your GQL schema look like that matches this resolve property? Does it actually expose an arg called filter?

Comment: Okay my fault. I really had no arg on the property. thx!